# preg_match_all 意図した通りに正規表現をマッチさせたい

Tags: php, 正規表現

下記のように `href` が `#title` から始まる `<a>` タグとその後ろの `<br>` タグを全て削除したいのですが、
現在のコードだと上手く `preg_match_all` が動作していません。
どう変更すればよいでしょうか？

**$content**

```html
<p>
<a href="#title1">stack</a>
<br>
<a href="#title2">overflow</a>
<br>
</p>
```

**現在のコード**

```php
if (preg_match_all('|<a href="#title.*?">(.*?)</a><br>|mis', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    if (!empty($matches)) {
        $content = preg_replace('|<a href="#title.*?">(.*?)</a><br>|mis', '', $content);
    }
}
```

Comment: `preg_match_all()` の場合、改行コードにマッチする `\R`(PCRE)を利用する事ができますので、`'|<a href="#title.*?">(.*?)</a>\R*<br>\R*|mis'` としてもよろしいかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

`</a>` と `<br>` の間に改行コード（`\r\n` or `\r` or `\n`）が入っているのではないかと思うので、該当部分を

```
</a>(\r\n|\r|\n)<br>
```

としたらどうでしょうか？